# HTML + CSS: z-index positioning

Tags: html, css, z-index

My webdesign is consisted of three parts.

- The red part is `<ul>`and `<li>`, classic list (menu).
- Yellow part is another list in previous red list (submenu) and
- blue part is normaly `<div>`.

I need the yellow list on top, blue in middle and red at the end only in HTML or CSS with z-indexes.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .menu {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                z-index: -2;
            }

            .submenu {
                z-index: 99999;
                font-size: x-large;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .obsah {
                position: relative;
                color: white;
                background-color: blue;
                width: 150px;
                height: 50px;
                z-index: -1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>MENU
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>SUBMENU</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="obsah">
            DIV
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you list your current html structure as well as styles?

Comment: something is missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is possible if the position of the yellow and blue are absolute

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
}

.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    font-size: x-large;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.obsah {
    position:absolute;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vg99o2bq/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use div with in "UL" list. However you can refer the part with :before and :after CSS Filters.

Answer (score 0):

So something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gqbgtu3x/)? Removing the position:relative; designation seemed to resolve the issue.

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 8;
}

.menu .submenu {
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: x-large;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.obsah {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but the blue part must be middle of red and yellow (red is at the bottom and yellow on the top).